# LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials when connecting jira to Mac OS X Lion Server LDAP

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, openldap, jira, osx-lion

I have the following setup:
- LDAP Server from Mac OS X running with default configuration
- JIRA Standlone installation

I want to:
Use LDAP for user authentication for jura

`username: cn=diradmin,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com`

`password: password of the diradmin`

I quadruppel checked the password, but I always get the `[LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]` as an error message.

Is there anything I have to do on the server side to allow the LDAP authentication by some third party app? Do I have to use the diradmin at all here? or can I use any user? what group has the user to be in?
I tried to do the same thing with hudson (build server). And there I get the exact same error message. So it's not a jira issue. It must be a configuration issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the username was wrong, I had to use this:

`uid=diradmin,cn=users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com`

For mor details: https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/#apd11ff4730